# Infinite loop while trying to do a function that i did in pyrthon

Tags: javascript, python

I am a 15 year old student from slovenia. I am fluent in pyhton and i am currently learning javascript as i like web development. I am doing some things i did in python. I am working on basically a square it has a double for loop that prints a square. This is the code in python:

```
def kvadrat(vnos):
    for i in range(vnos):
        vrstica = ""
        for j in range(vnos):
            if i==j:
                vrstica += "1 "
            else:
                vrstica += "0 "
        print(vrstica)

kvadrat(4)
```

I tried doing this in javascript and have failed. I always get a infinite loop and i need some help as i am totaly clueless as of what i am doing wrong. This is my javascript code

```
function kvadrat(vnos) {
    let vrstica
    for (var i=0; i < vnos; i++){
        vrstica = "";
        for (var j=0; j < vnos; i++){
            if (i==j){
                vrstica += "1 ";
            }else{
                vrstica += "0 ";
            }
        }
        console.log(vrstica)
    }
}

kvadrat(4);
```

Hopefully someone can point out to what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You have i++ in both loops

Comment: `j` is always 0, as it is never incremented using `j++` inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function kvadrat(vnos) {
    let vrstica
    for (var i=0; i < vnos; i++){
        vrstica = "";
        for (var j=0; j < vnos; j++){
            if (i==j){
                vrstica += "1 ";
            }else{
                vrstica += "0 ";
            }
        }
        console.log(vrstica)
    }
}

kvadrat(4);
```